# I am unable to send data to my database , getting no error

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-controller

> ```
>  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>  use  App\Models\Product;
>  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
>  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
>
>  class ProductController extends Controller
>  {
>
>  public function store(Request $request) {
>
>     $this->validate($request,[
>         'productName' =>'required|max:255',
>         'quantity' =>'required',
>         'weight' =>'required',
>         'boxes' =>'required',
>         'MRP' =>'required',
>         'costprice' =>'required',
>         'image' =>'required|image|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
>         'productDescription' =>'required',
>     ]);
>
>     $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
>
>     Product::create([
>         'productName' => $request->productName,
>         'quantity' => $request->quantity,
>         'weight' => $request->weight,
>         'boxes' => $request->boxes,
>         'MRP' => $request->MRP,
>         'costprice' =>$request->costprice,
>         'productDescription' =>$request->productDescription,
>         'image' =>$request->image->move(public_path('images'),$imageName),
>         'seller_id' => $request->user('seller')->id,
>         'category_id' => $request->category
>     ]);
>     
>
>     return back()->with('success','Product stocked Successfully...');  
>   }
>  
>   }
> ```
>
> > can't get the problem solved with this code here is my blade file whenever i am submitting form it is not inserting data in database which is a problem and i have checked everthing including model , migration etc. but not getting any error but still data is not getting submit
>
> ```
> <div class='w-75 justify-end'>  
>   <form action="{{ route('products') }}" class='w-100 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg mt-1' 
>    method='post'>
>    @csrf     
>    @if(session()->has('success'))
>      <div class='alert alert-success'>
>         <ul>
>            <li>{{ session()->get('success')}}</li>
>          </ul>
>        </div>
>    @endif
>
>   <fieldset class='w-100 inline-flex bg-grey scheduler-border'>
>   <legend class='text-secondary font-bold border-bottom w-50 text-left ml-4 px-10 py-1'>Add 
>      Product </legend>   
>     <div class='flex w-100'>    
>       <div class='control-group flex flex-col ml-3 mb-4 w-25 p-3'>
>           <label for="image" class='sr-only'>Image</label>
>           <input type="file" name='image' id='image'
>           class='form-control bg-gray-100 border-2 w-75 h-25 p-2 rounded-lg mb-4'>  
>
>           <label for="productName" class='sr-only'>Product Name</label>
>           <input type="text" name='productName' id='productName' placeholder= 'product Name' 
>           class='bg-gray-100 border-2 w-75 p-2 h-10 rounded-lg mb-8 @error('productName') ? 
>           border border-danger : '' @enderror' value='{{ old('productName') }}'>    
>
>
>           <label for="category" class='sr-only'>Category</label> 
>              <select type="dropdown" name='category' id='category'
>               class='bg-gray-100 text-secondary border-2 w-75 h-10 rounded-lg mb-2'>
>               <option selected>select category</option>
>                  @foreach($categoryname as $data) 
>                     <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->categoryName }}</option>
>                  @endforeach
>              </select>
>           
>              <div class='form-check w-100 ml-0 m-2 p-2'> 
>                <i>Status:</i> 
>                 <input class='form-check-input mt-2 ml-3' type="checkbox" 
>             name='flexCheckChecked'
>          id='flexCheckChecked' class='bg-gray-100 border-2 w-25 p-2 rounded-lg mb-4' checked>
>                 <label class='form-check-label ml-8' for="flexCheckChecked">active</label>
>             </div>
>       </div>
>          
>         <div class='control-group mb-4 p-3 w-50'>
>            <label for="product description" class='sr-only'>Product description</label>
>                <textarea  name='productDescription' id='productDescription' placeholder='Add 
>             product description' 
>                class='bg-gray-100 border-2 w-75 h-25 p-2 rounded-lg mb-2 
>           @error('productDescription') ? border border-danger : '' @enderror' value='{{ 
>             old('productDescription') }}' cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
>                
>            <div class='flex mt-2'>
>               <label for="Unit price" class='sr-only'>Unit price</label>
>               <input type="number" name='costprice' min=1 id='costprice' placeholder='Unit 
>                price' class='bg-gray-100 border-2 text-sm w-25 p-2 rounded-lg mb-4 
>                @error('costprice') ? border border-danger : '' @enderror' value='{{ 
>                old('costprice') }}'>
>                <small class='text-secondary p-2 font-italic'>(Rs.)</small>
>              
>
>                <label for="weight" class='sr-only'>weight</label>
>               <input type="number" name='weight' min=1 id='weight' placeholder= 'Weight' 
>                class='bg-gray-100 border-2 w-25 text-sm p-2 rounded-lg mb-4 ml-4 
>              @error('weight') ? border border-danger : '' @enderror' value='{{ old('weight') 
>              }}'>
>                <small class='text-secondary p-2 font-italic'>(g)</small>
>              
>             </div>
>
>             <div class='flex'>
>               <label for="quantity" class='sr-only'>Quantity</label>
>               <input type="number" name='quantity' min=1 id='quantity' placeholder= 'Quantity' 
>                class='bg-gray-100 border-2  text-sm w-25 p-2 rounded-lg mb-4 
>                 @error('quantity') ? border border-danger : '' @enderror' value='{{ 
>                old('quantity') }}'>
>                <small class='text-secondary p-2 font-italic'>(per box)</small>
>
>                <label for="boxes" class='sr-only'>Boxes</label>
>               <input type="number" name='boxes' min=1 id='boxes' placeholder= 'Boxes' 
>                class='bg-gray-100 border-2 w-25 p-2 rounded-lg mb-4 @error('boxes') ? border 
>                border-danger : '' @enderror' value='{{ old('boxes') }}'>
>                <small class='text-secondary p-2 text-sm font-italic'>(cartoon)</small>
>         
>            </div>
>
>             <div class='mb-4 flex justify-start'>
>                <input type="number" name='MRP' min=1 id='MRP' placeholder= 'MRP' 
>                class='bg-gray-100 border-2 w-25 text-sm p-2 rounded-lg mb-4 @error('MRP') ? 
>                border border-danger : '' @enderror' value='{{ old('MRP') }}'>
>                <small class='text-secondary p-2 font-italic mr-4'>(Rs.)</small>
>      
>                <button type="submit" class='w-25 h-10 bg-blue-500 text-white text-center font- 
>                medium py-1 rounded-lg'><b>+</b> Add Product</button>
>              </div> 
>            </div>
>          </div> 
>        </fieldset>
>     </form>  
>             <hr class='bg-grey-500'>
>      </div>
> ```
>
> I want my code to insert data in my database but it is getting back and not providing error
> or success if i check my database there is no data please resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
$request->validate($rules);
```

or

```
$request->validate([
    'productName' => 'required|max:255'
]);
```

Then it returns the errors.

```
$test = $productName->validate([
           'productName' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);
```

and you need to check if there are no errors and then you can do what ever you want.

In your case you need to do it like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'productName' => 'required|max:255'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->with('failed','There is error'); 
} else {
    return back()->with('success','Product stocked Successfully...'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks ur answer...got me the solution✊

Comment: @RitikRai please close this question, Click on Accept as answer option